# How can I make a list of tuples from two source lists, matching each possible element from the first to an element from the second?

Tags: python, list, python-itertools, cartesian-product

I have two lists, say `firstList = ['a','b','c']` and `secondList = [1,2,3,4]`.

I have to make a list of tuples by merging these lists in such a way that output should be like this

```
[('a',1),('a',2),('a',3),('a',4),('b',1), ('b',2) .....]
```

One simple way to do this is by

```
outputList = [] 
for i in firstList:
    for j in secondList:
        outputList.append((i,j))
```

How can I do this more simply?

Comment: What is the "custom condition" in your question title?

Comment: @Inbar Rose : My apologies...it should be 'given' instead of 'custom'.

Comment: Well - what is the given condition than?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> firstList = ['a','b','c']
>>> secondList = [1,2,3,4]
>>> from itertools import product
>>> list(product(firstList, secondList))
[('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('a', 3), ('a', 4), ('b', 1), ('b', 2), ('b', 3), ('b', 4), ('c', 1), ('c', 2), ('c', 3), ('c', 4)]
```

Also here's a nicer version of your for loops using a list comprehension:

```
>>> [(i, j) for i in firstList for j in secondList]
[('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('a', 3), ('a', 4), ('b', 1), ('b', 2), ('b', 3), ('b', 4), ('c', 1), ('c', 2), ('c', 3), ('c', 4)]
```

Comment: Great answer, +1. :) Just how I would have answered it (the list comprehension part)

Comment: This was what i was looking for..Thanks! which one will execute faster among these two ?

Comment: @user1863122 I'd always go for `product`, it should be a tonne faster for huge lists but the the difference is negligible in smaller ones.